# Set a Fixed Transparent Background Image under a div element

Tags: html, css

Title explains what I want to achive, here is the code:-

**HTML**

```
<div id="header-shadow"></div>
<div id="block">
  <div id="square"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#header-shadow {
    background: url(http://planetbounce.m360.co.uk/wp-content/themes/planetbounce/assets/img/header-shadow.png);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 10px;
    z-index: 0;
    position: fixed;
    top: 100px;
}

#block{
    height:1000px;
}

#square{
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px; background: red;
    margin-top: 200px;
    display: block;
    z-index: 9999999;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3je397xb/)

As you can see, on scroll the `#square` sits under the background image, is there any way to display this over the `#header-shadow`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, like this, where you can remove your `z-index` and set `position: relative` to `#block`.

```css
#header-shadow {
    background: url(http://planetbounce.m360.co.uk/wp-content/themes/planetbounce/assets/img/header-shadow.png);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 10px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 100px;
}

#block{
  position: relative;
  height:1000px;
}

#square{
  height: 100px; width: 100px; background: red; 
  margin-top: 200px; display: block; opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="header-shadow"></div>
<div id="block">
  <div id="square"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, although this does solve my fiddle, I'm applying the same CSS to http://planetbounce.m360.co.uk/ and it's not working here and I can't figure out why

Comment: @nsilva In that case you might want to try `z-index`, though set it on the `#block`, not the `#square`. Also, when you scroll, bootstrap/wordpress adds a class to the navbar, make sure that class is as well overridden by your own to make it work.